# Is there a straight-forward means of determining dependencies between packages

Tags: packages

I was reading about creating coordinate systems in the `pgfmanual` and was surprised to see the use of `\define@key` in one of the examples

```
\makeatletter
\define@key{cylindricalkeys}{angle}{\def\myangle{#1}}
\define@key{cylindricalkeys}{radius}{\def\myradius{#1}}
\define@key{cylindricalkeys}{z}{\def\myz{#1}}
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{cylindrical}%
{%
\setkeys{cylindricalkeys}{#1}%
\pgfpointadd{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{\myz}}{\pgfpointpolarxy{\myangle}{\myradius}}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[z=0.2pt]
\draw [->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,350);
\foreach \num in {0,10,...,350}
\fill (cylindrical cs:angle=\num,radius=1,z=\num) circle (1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I copied and pasted this into a document whose class was `article` and only loaded one package, `tikz`.  Everything compiled fine.

So I added a line to list the files:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\listfiles
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\define@key{cylindricalkeys}{angle}{\def\myangle{#1}}
\define@key{cylindricalkeys}{radius}{\def\myradius{#1}}
\define@key{cylindricalkeys}{z}{\def\myz{#1}}
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{cylindrical}%
{%
\setkeys{cylindricalkeys}{#1}%
\pgfpointadd{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{\myz}}{\pgfpointpolarxy{\myangle}{\myradius}}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[z=0.2pt]
\draw [->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,350);
\foreach \num in {0,10,...,350}
\fill (cylindrical cs:angle=\num,radius=1,z=\num) circle (1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I discovered that the following key value packages loaded:

```
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
```

I assumed (rather incorrectly, apparently) that it was the `pgfkeys` package loading these dependencies.  But, when I made a document which only used `pgfkeys`, the listed files were only:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 ***********
```

I could continue in this manner of loading only one package at a time and listing its package dependencies.  But that's rather tedious.  Is there in general a less tedious way to better discover how the various packages are depending upon one another?

Note:  I'm not asking just about `tikz` or `pgf`.  It was only via playing with those two packages that this question arose.

**Update**

It looks like [How to design a command inquiring internally required packages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122438/22413) provides something of a solution. 
Though the answer provided @HeikoOberdiek only seems to list the dependencies the first time they're encountered.  If a subsequent packages *requires* a package that has already been required, then it's not printed out a second time.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to know? Provided a package correctly loads its own dependencies, there should be no issues.

Comment: `tikz.sty` requires `pgf.sty` which requires `pgfcore.sty` which requires `keyval.sty`. Not easy to follow. The packages in the `oberdiek` bundle do something similar.

Comment: @JosephWright I guess I could be concerned with name conflicts.  But, in general, this is really a curiosity question.

Comment: You could redefine `\usepackage`, `\RequirePackage`, etc. to keep track of what loads what and save that information in a first pass, and produce some directed graph of dependencies between class/packages in a second pass, couldn't you? That would actually be a nice package.

Comment: @egreg  That's what I was able to figure out, but what I'm wondering is, without opening each `.sty` or `.code.tex` file and doing a file chanse, is there a more direct way provided to track down such chains of dependencies.  (Again, this isn't really a question about `tikz` or `pgf` per se.  They just happen to be large packages.)

Comment: Perhaps the answers to [How to design a command inquiring internally required packages?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119469/3954) could be of interest for you.

Comment: There is an answer here on tex.sx, i think bei Heiko Oberdiek producing some kind of loading tree in the log. But i can't find it.

Comment: @Jubobs That's a great idea.  Hmm.  Too bad I hadn't thought of that.  How about posting such an answer?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina That was exactly what i meant. :-)

Comment: @A.Ellett Well, it's just a suggestion. I don't have enough time to pursue that possibility, so I don't think it would be right to post it as an answer.

Comment: @A.Ellett if you consider that the answers there are in fact an answer to your question, then yes, I think this could be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: @A.Ellett Then, I guess we could mark it as duplicate if you agree.

Comment: I've started the "close" voting process.