# Any online available depiction(s) of LaTeX packages hierarchy?

Tags: packages

Here often we see statements *You don't need to load PGF because TikZ loads it*, or   *don't load TikZ because PGFplots already does that...*. I wonder if:

**Is there a tree diagram listing all these relationships/subordinations/rank between packages?**

Comment: Given the number of packages out there, you're asking for a very messy graph `:)`

Comment: As far as I understand, it doesn't matter that you call a package that has already been called by someone else before.  It just gets ignored when it is requested.  I think you can see what packages you are using with `\listfiles`

Comment: @MarioS.E. : it was good to know the redundancy is harmless - by the tone of the comments I referred to I was under the impression that this was not the case.  I was afraid it would re-load packages again. This info makes the question moot.

Comment: @SergioParreiras Nah, don't worry about re-loading.  *fica tranquilo, pá* :)

Comment: @MarioS.E. You can get errors if you have different optional arguments in the two cases: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=optclash

Comment: @TorbjørnT. yes, you're right.  Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Have a look at this answer by @Heiko: [How to design a command inquiring internally required packages?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122438)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\listfiles` to see what packages are *actually* loaded and can look through the log to see what loads what: TeX surrounds each file with a parenthesis pair [`( ... )`] so one can parse the log and work out dependencies. However, I would *strongly* suggest not doing this. In any document, you should know which packages provide which commands you use, and *explicitly load those packages*. It's a *very bad idea* to rely on package X always loading package *Y* (beyond a few places where the dependency is in a bundle of related packages, and there almost always the 'low level' one should not be used directly by users).