# vizualisation of package dependencies

Tags: packages, dependencies

According to the solution of Heiko

([How to design a command inquiring internally required packages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119469/how-to-design-a-command-inquiring-internally-required-packages))

I would like to have one additional file to be written...

It should have the form

Headerlines  > ptree.tex
child -> parent > ptree.tex
Footerlines > ptree.tex

line by line in an tex file

As an example...

The written file should have the form

```
\begin{dot2tex} 
strict digraph G { nodesep=0.01
graph [ overlap = false, fontsize = 10 ];
edge[weight=1.2];
"amstext [2000/06/29 v2.01]" -> "amsmath [2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features]";
"amsgen [1999/11/30 v2.0]" -> "amsmath [2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features]";
"..." -> "...";
\end{dot2tex}
```

As a result of this text file it can be displayed via graphViz.... (maybe I have to make an graphviz newline between package and version, so the nodes wont be as width as without newline.

But I am not aware about the newline graphviz code (node).

Is there any way to produce this code additional to the which is written to logfile?

desired output: additional texfile as described above.

Compiling will generate the tex-file. 
Compiling a new file will display the graph...