# TikZ standalone will not center

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, standalone, adjustbox

I am drawing a TikZ picture as a standalone file and then I use `\includestandlaone` in my main document. When I insert the file the picture is not centered even though I use `\centering`. How can I fix this?

MWE:

**Main file**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,mathtools,bm,amsthm,commath,esvect}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includestandalone[max width=0.5\textwidth]{./fig/partA_inventory_diagram}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**Standalone file**

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}    
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]


% define origin of coordinate system
\coordinate (origin) at (0,0);

\draw[<->] (0,-3) -- (0,7) node[above] {Inventory $Q$};
\draw[->] (origin) -- (10,0) node[right] {Time $t$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: can you move `\usetikzlibrary`  part before `\begin{document}` and try? and also remove the empty line before figure environment and add `\noindent`

Comment: Does that even work for you? I get `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package adjustbox.`, which can be fixed by making `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` the first package to be loaded. (And doing that it works fine.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. it works when I made it the first package to be loaded. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not ignore errors!

Your code produces an error saying

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package adjustbox.
```

which is caused by the fact that the `standalone` package loads the `adjustbox` package without options, and when you try to load again, with more options, you get an error.

Whenever a package is loaded more than once, the options passed to it the second time has to be a subset of the options passed to it the first time. Hence, load `adjustbox` *before* `standalone`, i.e. do

```
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{standalone}
```

instead of

```
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
```

and you're fine.

Comment: +1 Such a useful point! Is there any list of dependencies between all of `LaTeX` packages (or at least more applicatory ones)? I mean, how is one supposed to discern the nature of clashes?

Comment: @Roboticist I don't know, but I doubt it. Somewhat related though: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119469/how-to-design-a-command-inquiring-internally-required-packages/122438#122438 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24542/create-list-of-all-external-files-used-by-master-latex-document/24546#24546